# AJAX Toolkit Modal Popup won't appear

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm having some trouble calling a modal popup from server side.  So, I set the modalpopupextender's targetcontrolID to a hidden label.  Then in the codebehind from a button's click, I try to add this.modalpopup.show();  Unfortunately, the modal popup doesn't appear when this happens.  I can see the code get executed, but nothing shows.

Here's my ASP.  minus the opening < for the button and popupextender, because for some reason those lines won't display.

```
<asp:Button CssClass="Button" ID="button" runat="server" Text="Button" AccessKey="m" meta:resourcekey="buttonResource1" OnClick="button_Click" /> 

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="forpopup"
            PopupControlID="PopupPanel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />

       <asp:Label ID="forpopup" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>

        <asp:panel id="PopupPanel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderColor="black" BorderWidth="3px" BackColor="AliceBlue" Height="200px" Width="200px" style="display: none">

            <asp:Label ID="lblPopup" runat="server" Text="popup!"></asp:Label><br />
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlData" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList><br />
            <br />

            <asp:Button ID="btnPopupOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnPopupCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        </asp:panel>
```

and here is my codebehind

```
    protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.mpe.Show();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need the style: display=none.

But, can you also show the code for the popup extender?

Also, with the extender, you can point it at a button to display the popup without having to use the code behind.

Comment: the display=none prevents the popup from showing up on load, and then disappearing.  Standard practice.

Comment: please edit to show the definition of the popup extender... perhaps your issue is there.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't show my extender code, even though when I click on edit, it's there.  anyways, here it is.

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="forpopup"
            PopupControlID="PopupPanel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
       <asp:Label ID="forpopup" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>

Comment: That's directly above the panel code.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem.. I was setting the targetcontrolid of the extender to a hidden button and trying to fire the Show() event in server side code.  It wasn't being displayed even though the code was getting hit.  I discovered that the problem was that I was hiding the hidden button using "visible = false" which doesn't render the control to the page.  I changed it to "style='display:none'" and it started working.  Try changing your target control to a hidden button and make sure it's getting rendered (just not shown) and maybe it will work.

Comment: I made a note of this in my answer as I thought it may be relevant

Comment: I remember having that issue before too! Good catch Cody!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [ASP.NET AJAX ModalPopup documentation](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)

> `TargetControlID` is the ID of
>   the element that activates the modal
>   popup.

In your sample code, `TargetControlID` is set to a `Label ID="forpopup"`, yet in the code-behind you are attempting to show the ModalPopup using a click event handler for `Button ID="button"`.

Have you tried changing the `TargetControlID` to `"button"` and seeing if the ModalPopup appears?

A couple of notes

- What is the purpose of using `Label ID="forpopup"` for the `TargetControlID`?
- `Label ID="forpopup"` will not be rendered in HTML on the client.

**EDIT:**

Demo code to show use-

aspx content page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">    
  <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Open ModalPopup" />     

  <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="modal" BackgroundCssClass="darken" 
  CancelControlID="btnCancel" PopupControlID="pnl" TargetControlID="btnShow" />

  <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" style="width:55%;display:none;">
        <h1>You can now see me!</h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
        culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Close" />
  </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

code-behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        btnShow.Click += new EventHandler(btnShow_Click);
    }

    protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        modal.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, the issue with setting the TargetControl is that the popup is called client side, so my other functions underneath the button click don't run.  This is where it says to set it to a hidden control.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

This ModalPopup will be spawned programmatically. The ModalPopupExtender that this popup is attached to has a hidden TargetControl. The popup can be shown via server in code behind and on the client in script by calling the ModalPopupExtender methods to show and hide.

Comment: if the ModalPopup is called client-side, then set an OnClientClick attribute for your asp Button to run a JavaScript function to get the modal popup by id then call its show() function

Answer (score 1):

I typically add any kind of extenders after the buttons/panels/controls they are going to modify. I haven't seen anything directly in the guides about the controls that state they have to go this way, but I've run into too many issues when I put the extenders before the controls.

Try putting the extender after the panel and button(s) in question and see if that fixes things.

Comment: I tried moving it to the last thing before </asp:Content>, but still no dice :/

Comment: Hmmm </asp:Content> you say... Do you have this nested in an UpdatePanel or something as well? If so, you'll want to post that code too, since the nesting of these things can easily affect what works and what doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dillie-O, I think you will need an update panel in there if you are invoking it from the Serverside:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
  <asp:panel id="PopupPanel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderColor="black" BorderWidth="3px" BackColor="AliceBlue" Height="200px" Width="200px" style="display: none">
    ...
  </asp:panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

then

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.mpe.Show();
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

Comment: I've tested this and an UpdatePanel is not required - if the TargetControlID is set appropriately, the postback is intercepted and an async postback is made instead, which runs the server side code and sends a result back that causes the ModalPopup to be displayed.

Comment: @Russ Cam, What you are saying is true, IF the TargetControlID IS the control you're using to activate the popup. In this question it is not, @ashtame is activating the popup from the codebehind, right?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the BehaviourID attribute of ModalPopupExtender to some value, then you will be able to show and hide the modal popup.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with the Modal Popup not displaying when the TargetControlID button had

```
UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

Set it to "true" and see if that resolves your issue. If that works, and assuming you didn't want the button to submit, then you might need to stop the button from submitting the form when you don't want it to.